# PHP replace URL segment with str_replace();

Tags: php, string, replace, silverstripe

I have `"/foo/bar/url/"` coming straight after my domain name.

What I want is to find penultimate slash symbol in my string and replace it with slash symbol + hashtag. Like so: from `/` to `/#` (The problem is not how to get URL, but how to handle it)

How this could be achieved? What is the best practice for doing stuff like that?
At the moment I'm pretty sure that I should use str_replace();

UPD. I think `preg_replace()` would be suitable for my case. But then there is another problem: what should regexp look like in order to make my issue solved?

P.S. Just in a case I'm using `SilverStripe` framework (**v3.1.12**)

Comment: **"The problem is not how to get URL, but how to handle it"** I'm confused about what you need.

Comment: like `$uri . "#"`? it seems too easy.

Comment: The thing is, I know how to get string, I'm having issues with replacing penultimate slash with my pattern.
Why I'm telling you that I'm using SilverStripe framework and other stuff that could be kinda unrelated to my post - because of SilverStrtipe built-in features that I may not know yet. So like maybe there is easier way to achieve what I want, without using custom php code.

Comment: @TylerSebastian `$link = $this->Link();` it returns string like so `/foo/bar/url/` I want to handle it like so: `/foo/bar/#url` and link could have several more URL segments in it (I'm not saying that there are definitely only three segments like in my example, so basically there could be more than 3, or less than 3).

Comment: Oh. maybe `$m = explode($link, '/'); $m[count($m) - 1] = "#" . $m[count($m) - 1]; implode($m, '/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = '/foo/bar/url/';

if (false !== $last = strrpos($url, '/')) {
    if (false !== $penultimate = strrpos($url, '/', $last - strlen($url) - 1)) {
        $url = substr_replace($url, '/#', $penultimate, 1);
    }
}

echo $url;
```

This will output

```
/foo/bar/#url/
```

If you want to strip the last `/`:

```
echo rtrim($url, '/'); // print /foo/bar/#url
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that would function.  There are probably cleaner ways.

```
// Let's assume you already have $url_string populated
$url_string = "http://whatever.com/foo/bar/url/";

$url_explode = explode("\\",$url_string);
$portion_count = count($url_explode);

$affected_portion = $portion_count - 2; // Minus two because array index starts at 0 and also we want the second to last occurence

$i = 0;
$output = "";
foreach ($url_explode as $portion){

    $output.=$portion;

    if ($i == $affected_portion){
        $output.= "#";
    }

    $i++;

}

$new_url = $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you now have

```
$url = $this->Link(); // e.g. /foo/bar/my-urlsegment
```

You can combine it like

```
$handledUrl = $this->ParentID 
    ? $this->Parent()->Link() + '#' + $this->URLSegment
    : $this->Link();
```

where `$this->Parent()->Link()` is e.g. */foo/bar* and `$this->URLSegment` is *my-urlsegment*

`$this->ParentID` also checks if we have a parent page or are on the top level of SiteTree

Answer (score 1):

I might be tooooo late for answering this question but I thought this might help you. You can simply use `preg_replace` like as

```
$url = '/foo/bar/url/';
echo preg_replace('~(\/)(\w+)\/$~',"$1#$2",$url);
```

**Output:**

```
/foo/bar/#url
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this solved my problem:

```
$url = $this->Link();
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = substr_replace($url, '#', strrpos($url, '/') + 1, 0);
```